# Add values to the sum of a column based on another column in csv using Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say i have this dataframe:

```
Fruits  Price  Quantity
apple    12       10
pear     50       5
kiwi     42       20
kiwi     30       35
```

I want to do the sum like this grouping by fruits:

```
df.groupby(['Fruits'])['Price'].sum()
```

All good until now, but i want the price to be added to the sum halfed (price/2) for the columns where the quantity is above 10. How do i do this?

Comment: Have u tried anything that doesn't work? please share the error u are facing.

Comment: i am not facing any error, i searched on the internet for solutions but didn't find any, i just want for the rows where the quantity is above 10, the price will add to the sum halfed

Comment: You need the individual price to be halved or the sum of the grouped price?

Comment: I need the sum like this df.groupby(['Fruits'])['Price'].sum() , but where the quantity is above 10, the corresponding price to be added is halfed. Example from the data frame listed above: 12+50+(42/2)+ (30/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try making changes to the dataframe first and then calculate the sum after grouping.

```
df_clone = df.copy()
df_clone['Price'] = [df_clone['Price'].loc[i]/2 if df_clone['Quantity'].loc[i]<10 else df_clone['Price'].loc[i] for i in range(df_clone.shape[0])]
print(df_clone)
```

which will give:

```
    Fruits  Price   Quantity
0   apple   12.0    10
1   pear    50.0    5
2   kiwi    21.0    20
3   kiwi    15.0    35
```

and now you can group this new dataframe to get your output:

```
df_clone.groupby(['Fruits'])['Price'].sum()
```

which results in:

```
Fruits
apple    12.0
kiwi     36.0
pear     50.0
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

Comment: That seems about right, thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: glad it helped.